# Replace one multipage header Picture with a slider

Tags: jquery, html, css

On our site....  http://www.pbycatalina.com ....( Wordpress 3.8 Twenty Twelve) we have one header of a half aircraft used for every page and that worked fine until now.
We have built a timeline slider using html, css and jquery flies and code and would like to use the same header picture and the same size header picture but use a manual slider bar to move the header picture (On only ONE Page)out the left side of the page dragging in the new (but hiding) timeline pictures and content. We understand this can be done quite easily below the header as content but not what we want.
This is (An Example Only) basically how it will react. http://www.jimpattison.com/corporate-info/default.aspx

I suppose my question is: With our slider project complete with both pictures and narrative content (though not visible).... is it possible to adapt a single page header in WordPress Twenty Twelve to accept the slider using the same header picture?
If our slider code would be of value I am happy to include all 1.9mb of the folder.

Answer (score 0):

Put your slider code into a template file within twenty-twelve. In `header.php` you'll need to wrap the existing code within `<header id="masthead">` in a conditional check.

```
<header id="masthead" class="site-header" role="banner">
    <?php if ( is_page( 'home' )): //replace 'home' with the page slug or ID you want ?>
        <?php get_template_part('your-slider-template'); ?>
    <?php else: ?>
        <hgroup>
            <h1 class="site-title">...
            <h2 class="site-description"><?php bloginfo( 'description' ); ?></h2>
        </hgroup>
        ... the rest of the header ...

    <?php endif; ?>
</header><!-- #masthead -->
```

You'll want to use [wp_enqueue_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) to load the javascript and [wp_enququq_style](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style) to load the CSS your slider needs via your theme's functions.php file. You can (and should) [load those conditionally as well](http://www.organizedthemes.com/loading-scripts-conditionally/).